# Can't get factory or service to be recognized in controller with angluarjs using angular-seed

Tags: service, controller, angularjs, factory

I keep getting "undefined is not a function" when calling the factory. I am using the angular-seed as the framework for my setup. For some reason, it doesn't recognize "GetFormVals" as a valid factory.

In app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.filters',
'myApp.services', 'myApp.directives'], function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    //route declarations
    $routeProvider.when('/fsr', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/fsr.html',
        controller: ctrlFSR
    });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

In controllers.js:

```
function ctrlFSR($scope, $http, $location, GetFormVals) {
    $scope.test = GetFormVals();
}
ctrlFSR.$inject = ['$scope','$location'];
```

In services.js:

```
'use strict';

/* Services */

angular.module('myApp.services', []).
    factory('GetFormVals', function(){
    return "test";
});
```

I have to be missing something simple.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wUjw5/11/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to list all the dependencies to be injected into your controller:

```
function ctrlFSR($scope, $http, $location, GetFormVals) {
    $scope.test = GetFormVals();
}
ctrlFSR.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', '$location', 'GetFormVals'];
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, but the $http service needs to be injected as well. See http://jsfiddle.net/wUjw5/13/ Or if you're not using a js minifier, just get rid if the `$inject`. See http://jsfiddle.net/wUjw5/14/

Answer (score 1):

Change your service to this

```
'use strict';

/* Services */

angular.module('myApp.services', []).
    factory('GetFormVals', function(){
            return {
                exampleValue: "test5"
            }
    });
```

Then in your controller you would update it to this:

```
function ctrlFSR($scope, $http, $location, GetFormVals) {
    $scope.test = GetFormVals.exampleValue;
}
ctrlFSR.$inject = ['$scope','$location'];
```

I think the confusion came in with you calling GetFormVals as a function, while in reality it's a service.

**jsfiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/rtCP3/49/

---

**your js fiddle modified** http://jsfiddle.net/wUjw5/12/

Don't inject with ctrlFSR.$inject = ['$scope','$location'];. You already are.

Comment: thanks for the quick response. I tried that, now I am getting "Cannot read property 'exampleValue' of undefined" error.

Comment: Whoops, you're right, i got it confused with the actual .service method. I've posted a jsfiddle and modified my answer.

Comment: still didn't work. again thanks for helping. i created a jsfiddle with my code: http://jsfiddle.net/wUjw5/11/

I also injected the factory per pkozlowski.opensource reco, but that did't help either.

Comment: You are injecting stuff twice, and i feel that's what's causing the problem.

Comment: Matt, your first post helped troubleshoot, and I needed the inject for minification. Thanks for all the help!!